# Nested attribute term Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have a documents something like bellow

`{
        "_index": "lines",
        "_type": "lineitems",
        "_id": "4002_11",
        "_score": 2.6288738,
        "_source": {
          "data": {
            "type": "Shirt"
          }
        }
      }`

I want to get a count based on type attribute value. Any suggestion on this?

I tried term query but no lick with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the terms aggregation, this will return the number of documents aggregated for each "type" field values.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html